# I change img picture src in javascript, but the img do not refresh, how to refresh it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, image

I change the img src in javascript from:

```
http://loclhost:8080/mvc/resources/pics/625bd317-b71c-4d74-aff2-248b86ff900b.jpg
```

to

```
http://loclhost:8080/mvc/resources/pics/4c1541ab-204c-4eff-b641-8527294e02cd.jpg
```

my code is:

```
 function selectdef(pic){
     var picid=pic.split('.')[0];
       $.ajax({    
            type:'post',        
            url:'defaultset/<c:out value="${pbid}"/>/'+picid,    
            data: {picid   : pic},    
            cache:false,    

            success:function(data){
                            //when ajax require success I will change the picture src
                $(".products li img").src='<c:out value="${path}/"/>'+pic;

            },
            error: function(e){
               alert(e.massage());
               }   
        });

     }
```

my change src line is:

```
 $(".products li img").src='<c:out value="${path}/"/>'+pic;
```

but the picture is till not change

But the img do not refresh, only I reload the page again it can refresh? why? I think the src different the img should be refresh?

how to refresh it?

Comment: Yeah, it will. If the JavaScript's correct, may we see that? And your HTML?

Comment: I change pic with:$(".products li img").src='<c:out value="${path}/"/>'+pic;  the really address or the script is /mvc/resources/pics/77f5f21c-fa3c-4508-aaa3-8eca3a88be3f.jpg I confirm I have picture there as if I refreshed the page the picture show. the UUID is random generated by server so every-time it will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery to change the image's `src` attribute, you can do this through the `attr` method:

```
$(".products li img").attr('src', '<c:out value="${path}/"/>' + pic);
```

If you wanted to use the native `src` attribute, you would need to access the DOM element first before using the `src` attribute:

```
$(".products li img")[0].src = '<c:out value="${path}/"/>' + pic;
```

My recommendation would be to use the jQuery `attr` method.

Comment: I change pic with:$(".products li img").src='<c:out value="${path}/"/>'+pic; the really address or the script is /mvc/resources/pics/77f5f21c-fa3c-4508-aaa3-8eca3a88be3f.jpg I confirm I have picture there as if I refreshed the page the picture show. the UUID is random generated by server so every-time it will change.

Answer (score 0):

That is my fault: I use jquery in wrong way:

```
$(".products li img").src='<c:out value="${path}/"/>'+pic;
```

The corret use should be:

```
$('.productdefault li img').prop("src", '<c:out value="${path}/"/>'+pic);
```

the jDom could not just simple use DOM staff.